# how to update files in existing cordova project android platform?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

how to update files in existing cordova project android platform?

i converted my web app to cordova app to go native - 
i uploaded the cordova app to the play store, and now i want to upload a newer version of the app - the problem is that i don't know how to update the files in the existing cordova project without deleting it and start all over again - 
i have multiple plugins in the older cordova project and do not wish to start from the beginning and install them.
my OS is windows 10 , and i work with Android Studio

Comment: I believe to update the app, after switching to native you have to have the same package name and the key-store file you created when publishing the cordova app, or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: from play store point of view , i have everything - keystore file and same package name - my problem is that i don't know how to update the 'android' folder in the project with the new code files

Answer (score 0):

You can make your changes in the `www/` folder of the project (where your web code is housed), and then run [`cordova prepare`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#cordova-prepare-command) ... this will essentially copy your `www` files to the platform (Android in this case) specific location.

You can then rebuild in Android Studio or by running `cordova build android`

This way your plugins are untouched and only the web code is updated.